# How to solve 3D multi bin-packing with OpenOpt

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, bin-packing

I'm learning about optimization and I'm new to OpenOpt.

I would like to represent processes where each have 3 resources usage indicators (CPU, memory and network), and I would like to assign N processes to groups / bins according to the following restrictions:

```
sum(cpu) within a group < 100
sum(mem) within a group < 100
sum(net) within a group < 100
Minimize(number of groups) or maximize the sum of each resource within a group.
```

Ideally I would like to have this type of output:

```
VM 1 assigned to group 1
VM 2 assigned to group 1
VM 3 assigned to group 1
VM 4 assigned to group 2
VM 5 assigned to group 2
VM 6 assigned to group 3
... and so on
```

Quesiton: How can I do that? If it is not possible to do this with OpenOpt, is there any other lib that could help me with this?

Here my initial code:
https://github.com/vonpupp/mdbp/blob/master/ksp_2.py

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to assign a weight on each item (in this case, all are the same), and maximize the number of items limited by the constraints.

This is how the items are created:

```
def gen_vms():
    tg = tracegen.TraceGenerator()
    trace = tg.gen_trace()
    items = [{
                  'name': 'item %d' % i,
                  'weight': 1,
                  'cpu': t[0],
                  'mem': t[1],
                  'disk': t[2],
                  'net': t[3],
                  'n': 1
             } for i,t in islice(enumerate(trace), 200)]
    return items
```

And this is how the constraints are created:

```
def add_constraint(values, constraint):
    return values[constraint] < 99

def add_constraints(values, constraint_list):
    return [add_constraint(values, constraint) for constraint in constraint_list]

def gen_costraints(constraint_list):
    global constraints
    constraints = lambda values: (add_constraints(values, constraint_list))
```

The solving process is like this:

```
def solve_host():
    global items
    global constraints
    p = KSP('weight', list(items), constraints = constraints)
    result = p.solve('glpk', iprint = -1)
```

Further details on how to do this can be found here: https://github.com/vonpupp/2013-sbrc-experiments/blob/e2e8a2be320c8f77d67a5bc6bb822510564e80f3/myksp_oo.py

Comment: where is lib.tracegen.tracegen from in your gist?

Comment: You can browse the code from that particular commit directly on github (it's not a gist, it's a full repo). If you are looking for the tracegen.py, you can find it here: https://github.com/vonpupp/2013-sbrc-experiments/blob/e2e8a2be320c8f77d67a5bc6bb822510564e80f3/lib/tracegen/tracegen.py